# Har File Monitoring

Tags: selenium, selenium2, java

I'm looking to automate some testing of calls we make to an external service.  I've gotten Browsermob-proxy and selenium to play together nicely.  I'd now like to monitor the requests as they occur, however I am receiving a ConcurrentModificationException in line 5 of the below loop:

```
while (!found) {
    har = server.getHar();
    HarLog harLog = har.getLog();
    List<HarEntry> entries = harLog.getEntries();
    for (HarEntry entry : entries) { //Exception occurs on this line
        for (HarNameValuePair queryData : entry.getRequest().getQueryString()) {
            found = (queryData.getName().compareToIgnoreCase("events") == 0)
                 && (queryData.getValue().contains("event5"));
            if (found) {
               //Do some processing & break out
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this something I should be doing with a [HttpRequestInterceptor](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor.html) instead?

A slight modification to the example will allow this code to work:

```
List<HarEntry> entries = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<HarEntry>(harLog.getEntries());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created [Issue 39](https://github.com/webmetrics/browsermob-proxy/issues/39), due to the request made at [browsermob-proxy google group](http://groups.google.com/group/browsermob-proxy/browse_thread/thread/c5bcf3a70e40c955).